# how to add a country picker in a bootstrap form using select tag?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="country">Country:</label>
           <select class="form-control bfh-countries" data-country="US"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I want to select the countries using this form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd probably rather bring in the countries via SQL. Though, if you're going to manually enter them, just add the `<option>` tag with a value and text.

```html
 <div class="col-sm-6">
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="country">Country:</label>
           <select class="form-control bfh-countries" data-country="US">
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
           </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for you help. But if i add bootstrap form helpers, then can i pick any country from the list?

Comment: What do you mean "can I pick any country from the list"? The Bootstrap form classes don't affect the actual list of countries.